# Disable multi select?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is there a way to disable multi select?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but updates to Slickgrid now allow you to disable multiSelect in the grid options:

```
var options = {
            editable: false,
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            asyncEditorLoading: false,
            multiSelect: false
        };
```

With this option, clicking while holding a ctrl or shift does nothing, and undesirably, you cannot deselect a cell with ctrl + click, or clicking the selected cell again

Comment: This doesn't stop someone from holding down shift key and then arrow key to multiselect ....

Answer (score 7):

In don't know of any setting to disable it.

handle the `onSelectedRowsChanged` event and do something like:

```
var selectedRows = grid.getSelectedRows();
if( selectedRows.length > 1 ) {
  grid.setSelectedRows( [ selectedRows[ selectedRows.length - 1 ] ] );
}
```

Comment: Unless there's a way to suppress triggering the event again, isn't this a closed loop?

Answer (score 1):

with this code you can disable multiselect:

```
document.getElementById('mySelectBox').removeAttribute("multiple");;
```

... of a selectbox like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="mySelectBox">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>        
</select>
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `muiltiple="multiple"` in the following line:

```
<select id="id" name="name" multiple="multiple">
```

So, it is as good as removing that attribute. I'd use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="3">
    <option value="1" disabled>One</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: we need to disable options to disable multi select

Comment: I don't see any other answer which adds `disabled` attributes to the `<option>` tags @StephenRauch. I don't know if this is the *correct* solution, but it's certainly *different* from the other answers.

Comment: As long as it works, this is a solution. Cheers Martin

Comment: The multiple attribute is a boolean attribute, it specifies that multiple options can be selected at once. Like selected we can use disabled attribute in options. We can use both together which is not possible with disabled="true" in select tag.

Answer (score -2):

Regarding your question, disable to multiple select is quite simple? Isn't it?

```
<select multiple="multiple" disabled = "true">
    <option value="1"> One
    <option value="2"> Two
    <option value="3"> Three        
</select>
```