# Get single row using checkbox in SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a table with checkbox for each row and i want to get only current(last) selected row using Slickgrid and Javascript.

I am aware of [getSelectedRows](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#user-content-getSelectedRows) function of Slickgrid, that returns an array of row indices corresponding to the currently selected rows.But can't find a method to return only last selected row.

Comment: Describe better your problem, what have you tried, what have you done, what you have accomplished, what do you get, what do you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select only current selected row, you could handle the

> onSelectedRowsChanged event

and do something like:

```
var selectedRows = grid.getSelectedRows();
if( selectedRows.length > 1 ) {
  grid.setSelectedRows( [ selectedRows[ selectedRows.length - 1 ] ] );
}
```

Already answered from Chris Hogan!

["Disable" multi select in the grid options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527493/disable-multi-select#answer-3589210)

> [jsfiddle working Test](http://jsfiddle.net/oikonomopo/5ds54Lok/7/)

Comment: If this is what you want, consider to accept the answer.